# Mongo $toDecimal rounded up number in aggregator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Schema

```
amount: Number
```

Input Data

```
{ amount: 1407633616694783200000 }
```

Since the schema is a number it will be stored as

```
{ amount: 1.4076336166947832e+21 }
```

When I try to do the aggregator with this query

```
'$project': {
  'amount': {
    '$toDecimal': '$amount'
   }
 }
```

The result return

```
{ amount: 1.40763361669478E+21 }
```

The difference between those two values is **3200000**

What happened here? Why mongo is showing different numbers and how to solve this because when I try to add or subtract it with another number. The result is not summed up incorrectly.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rwcW_Li1nHL)

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the `double` BSON type, which is used to store the amount here

From [mongodb numeric decimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/#numeric-decimal):

> The decimal BSON type uses the IEEE 754 decimal128 decimal-based
> floating-point numbering format. Unlike binary-based floating-point
> formats (i.e., the double BSON type), decimal128 does not approximate
> decimal values and is able to provide the exact precision required for
> working with monetary data.

So if you need exact precision, use `NumberDecimal("1407633616694783200000")`

see the [updated playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FlnpUe6zZ3M)